# Check for Valid XML in SQL Server 2005 trigger

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

I'm trying to write a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger that will take a `MESSAGE` column of type `VARCHAR(MAX)` and attempt to convert it to `XML`. If the `MESSAGE` is not valid `XML` (malformed), I simply want to pass on the original `MESSAGE`. If it is valid XML, I want to modify it a bit and then insert the modified version.

My first attempt was to use a `TRY/CATCH` inside the trigger like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
    SET @Message = (SELECT CONVERT(XML, inserted.[MESSAGE], 1) FROM inserted)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    --Cast failed.  Insert without XML parsing.
    GOTO InsertOriginal
END CATCH

...Perform work on XML and do the insert
```

Problem is, the failed conversion "dooms" the implied trigger transaction and even though execution runs to completion, the overall transaction fails.

So I then tried this

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION XmlCastTrans;

BEGIN TRY
    SET @Message = (SELECT CONVERT(XML, inserted.[MESSAGE], 1) FROM inserted)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION XmlCastTrans;

    --Cast failed.  Insert without XML parsing.
    GOTO InsertOriginal
END CATCH

COMMIT TRANSACTION XmlCastTrans;
```

That doesn't work either, as I get a `cannot roll back XmlCastTrans. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found` error.  How can I get this to work?

This is using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Your approach has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select? It's totally non-deterministic - plus you select only one row and ignore the 24 others.... You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: That is a good point to consider in general, but in this case, I can assume that the app making the call only ever inserts a single row at a time.

Comment: Try adding `SET XACT_ABORT OFF` before your Try-Catch block.

Comment: Nope, that only made it worse.  Instead of just the one error, multiple errors stacked on each other occurred.  Execution appears to skip over the failed ROLLBACK statement, but once the trigger finished, a bunch of "DOOMED" transaction errors appeared again and the entire insert statement rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

If your XML data is in a predictable format could you consider adding a binding to a schema collection on the XML column to enforce good inserts?

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176009(v=sql.90).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176009%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot assume that the XML is well-formed. It's a logging service for SOAP messages, and it will log every attempt, even if the client sends malformed XML. That's why I need to handle the case where the cast/conversion fails.